# conseguir la llave de un arreglo y la suma de todos sus miembros

Tags: php, json

Hace poco entre a un examen de php nivel junior y me pidieron realizar 4 ejercicios en un periodo de 1:30 minutos 
Tristemente fallé, pero me quede con la duda ya que no pude hacer "nada!" por mas que intenté un método tras otro.

El problema es muy similar a este :
En el archivo PHP, escriba un programa para realizar una solicitud `GET` en la ruta www.com que contiene una clave de datos y el valor es una cadena que contiene elementos en el formato: `key = CADENA, age = INTEGER`.

1. El objetivo es saber cuántos elementos existen con `age`
2. De estos, ¿Cuántos son superiores a 50?

Ejemplo:

```
{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47", key=jwdfy, age=41", key=nbf4g, age=27"}
```

Resultado : `2`

El problema me entrega el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php 

  $ch = curl_init('https://age-counting');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

   print_r(json_decode($data, true));

?>
```

Traté de descomponer el arreglo , o introducir `json_decode($data, true)` a una variable y sumar primero la funcion `count` para tener mi primer resultado antes de apuntar a "`age`" con `$data, ['age']` pero nunca me regreso mas que errores fatales.

Cuál es el tema que tendría que revisar o cuál fue el error en mi aproximación ya que al no poder hacer una cuenta no pude pasar al filtro de si es `<= 50`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifique el data para poder realizar el ejemplo, pero debería de funcionar también contigo.
Quizá con esto de hagas una idea.

```
<?php 
$data = json_encode([
  "data" => "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=jwdfy, age=41, key=nbf4g, age=27",
]);

$response = json_decode($data, true);
$response = explode(",", str_replace(" ", "", $response["data"]));
foreach($response as $items){
  $response2 = explode('=', $items);
  if($response2[0] == "age"){
    print_r($response2);
  }
}
```

Solo tendrías que agregar un if($response2[1] > 50) antes de imprimirlo.
Espero te haya servido de algo

Comment: la verdad , al no tener el arreglo que me regresa el link que vi en la prueba no estoy muy seguro si es el resultado. intente algo similar pero no me funciono pero creo que as agregado un par de cosas , en base a que estoy aprendiendo podrías explicarlo un poco mas ,^^ . igual mente creo que es el camino correcto gracias

Comment: al probarlo en mi compilador todo funciona (asta lo que probe que no funcionaba) y parece que funciona : <?php

$data = json_encode([
  "data" => "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=jwdfy, age=41, key=nbf4g, age=27",
]);

$response = json_decode($data, true);
$response = explode(",", str_replace(" ", "", $response["data"]));
foreach($response as $items){
  $response2 = explode('=', $items);
  if($response2[0] == "age" && $response2[1] >= 50 ){
    

        print_r($response2);
        print_r(count($response2 ));
   
        
  }
}
?>

Comment: En cuanto tu primer comentario, únicamente tome la información que pusiste.
También en el primer explode podrías usar " " en vez de ",".
Quizá haciendo var_dump($data) en el código original podrías ver como manejarlo.